# Can we change start date of auto-renewable subscription plan for iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, swift, subscription

We are working on an app right now and want to add a referral program in it. We are thinking a subscription-based model and want to extend free trial period if the user invites a friend and that friend will also get 7 days more on trial period. My question is if a user already subscribed and a first deduction will be on 1st June, how can we change it to 8th June after inviting friends? And Apple allows this? Please share code to how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: “Please share code to how to do this”, this is not how it works here, you are supposed to ask questions about problems with _your_ code not request us to write code for you. In regard to the question, you normally extend a period  by moving the end date, not the start date.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: It isn't possible to extend the duration of a given trial. The only way is to offer another one.

Apple provides you two ways to provide trials. As far as I undestand your intended behavior, you would need to combine both.

The first way is to provide a trial before paying, by offering an [introductory offer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_introductory_offers_in_your_app). For each subscription you can create an individual introductory offer with its own duration. Each user can only receive one introductory offer per subscription group (see [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve1d49254f) for detailed information and how to create introductory offers). That‘s the reason why you also need the second way, though.

The second way is done by offering a [subscription offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_subscription_offers_in_your_app). Those can be granted as often as you wish, but require the user to have an active re-newable subscription (which he has, if he used your introductory offer).

Unfortunately the second way isn't simple to implement. You need a server to validate receips and to allow users to register, so you have a way to identify them. Also the server is responsible for generating the subscription offers.

You see subscriptions isn't an easy topic and so I hope you can understand that I and probably no one else can write you the code to achieve this. Apple provides a lot of informations and example code in the links I‘ve added. Work those through and come back with your code related questions and I think everyone will gladly answer them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using iOS subscription but you may need to **create your own logic for free trial** and remove trial from in-app subscription plan. In this way, you can promt user to subscribe after your custom free trail or even after extended free trial.